# How to change colour of selected item & set fonts & colour in listview

Tags: android, listview

I have created a list view using intents but to improve the user experience of my app how can i change the colour of the selected item in the list view i have used the ListActivity class directly rather than a list view from the pallette so i would need to add the code to the activity directly here is my code

```
public class BreakfastListView extends ListActivity {

    static final String[] breakfood = {
        "Strawberry shake",
        "Egg muffin",
        "Morning sundae",
        "Peanut butter pancakes w banana",
        "Dippy eggs w marmite soldiers",
        "Breakfast burrito",
        "Ham and cheese muffin",
        "Bacon, egg and cheese bagel",
        "Yoghurt mashup",
        "Hot cereal mashup"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, breakfood));
        // Setting up the list array above

        }

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id){
        super.onListItemClick(lv, v, position, id);
        String openbreakclass = breakfood[position];
        if( "Strawberry shake".equals(openbreakclass))
        {
         Intent selectedIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Strawberry_Shake.class );
                               startActivity(selectedIntent);
        } else if("Egg muffin".equals(openbreakclass))
        {
         Intent selectedIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Egg_muffin.class );
                                startActivity(selectedIntent);  
        }else if("Morning sundae".equals(openbreakclass)){
            Intent selectedIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Morning_sundae.class );
            startActivity(selectedIntent);
        }else if("Peanut butter pancakes w banana".equals(openbreakclass)){
            Intent selectedIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Peanut_butter_pancakes_w_banana.class );
            startActivity(selectedIntent);
        }else if("Dippy eggs w marmite soldiers".equals(openbreakclass)){
            Intent selectedIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Dippy_eggs_w_marmite_soldiers.class );
            startActivity(selectedIntent);
        }else if("Breakfast burrito".equals(openbreakclass)){
            Intent selectedIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Breakfast_burrito.class );
            startActivity(selectedIntent);
        }else if("Ham and cheese muffin".equals(openbreakclass)){
            Intent selectedIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Ham_and_cheese_muffin.class );
            startActivity(selectedIntent);
        }else if("Bacon, egg and cheese bagel".equals(openbreakclass)){
            Intent selectedIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Bacon_egg_and_cheese_bagel.class );
            startActivity(selectedIntent);
        }else if("Yoghurt mashup".equals(openbreakclass)){
            Intent selectedIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Yoghurt_mashup.class );
            startActivity(selectedIntent);
        }else if("Hot cereal mashup".equals(openbreakclass)){
            Intent selectedIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Hot_cereal_mashup.class );
            startActivity(selectedIntent);
        }

    }
```

Comment: You can use the *position* to refer to the index in the array to remove the big if else statement and it would be easier for users seeing it here

Answer (score 0):

**1st**

Can i ask you, what you do if you have a 100 items in list view? You check every item in your array?

**To problem:**

If you want to change color or font or something else attribute you must do it in adapter.

Such as

```
...
View view=convertedView;
if(view ==null)
    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title)).setTextColor(Color.BLACK); // or what you want
...
```

**Updated**

So if you want to change color just create a class extended `BaseAdapter`(or similar) and according to my answer correcting `getView` method.

Comment: Sorry i didnt really get that sorry about the long code im sort of a beginner still

Comment: Would you say using the listview in the pallette would be easier for me rather than directly referencing the listactivity class

Comment: ListActivity is just a similar wrapper on ListView. Google it on Custom List View.